# The animation of my hero logo in flutter does not work every time I exit the app and come back or on the first start

Tags: flutter

I have read this documentation https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/rendering/shader but I don't think this is my case because I have problems not only on the first start of the app. I attach the widget that causes me problems:

```
class MyHeroLogo extends StatelessWidget {
  final double width;
  const MyHeroLogo({
    Key? key,
    required this.width,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Hero(
      tag: "MyHeroLogo",
      child: SizedBox(
        width: width,
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/images/RemindayLogo.png',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Here is an explanatory video]

Comment: Seems like a problem related to Navigation. Try passing a key to `MyHeroLogo` .

Comment: Sorry but I think I don't understand what you mean. Can you show me how?

Comment: Pass a key like this where you use the widget
 `keyMyHeroLogo(key:UniqueKey(),);`